# Add body overlay when a sidebar menu opens

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a working sidebar menu that opens up when clicked. However, the background overlay doesn't work efficiently as the website has many elements. Here's the JS that does the work of adding background color to opacity of 0.4

```
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("mainbody").style.marginRight = "0";
    jQuery("body").addClass("mySidenav_intro");
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
}
```

When clicked; the body of the pages change to

```
<body id="mainbody" class="mySidenav_intro" style="margin-right: 0px; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);">
```

However, it changes only the background color of the website. I want to create an overlay of sort like a modal does when it opens. How should I achieve this?

Comment: Isn't it simpler to write `$("#mySidenav")` instead of `document.getElementById("mySidenav")` ?

Comment: As you already know, from the provided code we cannot even guess what you're seeing on your screen so make sure to provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Rather than change the background colour of the body, what you want is an element that will sit on top with some opacity, for instance using the approach [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_fullscreen_overlay.asp).

At its simplest, you could have a div with class `overlay`, use JS to trigger an `enabled` class on it, and use CSS:

```
.overlay {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}
.overlay.enabled {
  display: initial;
}
```

By default this will cover everything, to keep it from covering your sidebar just make sure it has a z-index higher than the overlay (i.e. 2).